# How to get the n if I know the result of 1+2+3+..+n=n*(n+1)/2?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

If you know the result of `1+2+3+..+n`, which is `n*(n+1)/2`.
For example, if the result is `5050`, then I can know `n` is `100`. How can I obtain the `n`. However, you can only calculate the `n` by only **addition** and **substraction**.

And I know how I can get the `n` i is that I can traverse the natural number from 1 to n, by computing per different `1+2+3+...+n`, like `1`, `1+2`, `1+2+3`,...`1+2+..+n`, then I can check every result to `5050`, then I can find the `n` is `100`. But I find that the calculating steps will over 2000 steps, **so there is a good algorithm to find the `n`?**
Thanks!.

Comment: Adding the numbers from 1 to 100 should only take you 100 steps, not 2000.

Comment: Edit your **tag** and add what kind of **programming language**

Comment: @melpomene, not from 1 to 100, but from 1 to 2, then 1 to 3, until 1 to 100, then you can find the correct n.

Comment: @k-five, there is no specific programming language, but the language can only support *addition* and *substraction*. And I want a good algorithm to the problem.

Comment: @zhenguoli Why restart from 1 every time? If you just computed 1+2+...+n, you can get 1+2+...+n+(n+1) by simply adding n+1 to your previous result.

Comment: Why not simply solve the quadratic equation?

Comment: @melpomene, thanks, your idea is wonderful. Thanks!.

Comment: @adamwy, I have said that the programming language just support the *addtion* and *substraction*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only by **addition** and **subtraction**...
Simply add numbers from 1 and check whether the sum is the given number.

In pseudocode.
Given 5050.

```
number := 5050
next, sum := 0
while sum <= number
  next := next + 1
  sum := sum + next
return next
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want.

Comment: you should change the condition in the loop to `while sum <= number`. Otherwise this code will produce an infinite loop, if `number` isn't of the form `1 + 2 + ... + n`.

Comment: @Paul, yes. Edited, but tbh I only cared about the algorithm being correct for allowed input `number`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that:

```
1 + 2 + ... + N = V = N(N+1)/2
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
N^2 + N - 2V = 0
```

The value you are looking for is thus:

```
(-1+sqrt(1+4*2*value))/2;
```

That is one of the zeros of the given quadratic equation.

---

In C++ you can use a function like this:

```
int rev(int value) {
    return (-1+std::sqrt(1+4*2*value))/2;
}
```

Comment: "However, you can only calculate the n by only addition and substraction."

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `1 + 2 + .. + n = n*(n+1)/2 = r` (`r` is known `n` and is unknown).

Now we want to know the positive value of `n` for which the above equation is satisfied.

#### Theoretical method

We have,
`n^2+n=2*r`
`=> (n+1/2)^2 = 2*r + 1/4`
`=> n + 1/2 = sqrt(2*r+1/4)` (taking only the `+ve sqrt` since `n>0`)
`=> n = sqrt(2*r+1/4) - 1/2`
For example, `r=55 => n =10`, which can be found in O(1) time by plugging the value of `r`.

#### Numerical method

Now, we may fidn the solution numerically as well, by finding the positive root of the equation `(n^2+n)/2-r=0`. If `r=55`, the graph of the quadratic equation looks like the following, the root can be found out numerically by using `bisection` or `newton-raphson` like numerical methods. The following graph of the quadratic polynomial shows that `n=10` for `r=55`.

[image]